# Not able to identify element on Google Home page

Tags: xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to enter text on search text box on google home page. That I can identify using xpath as `//*[@id="q"]`. But I wanted to reach to that element using parent child relationship. I am using xpath as below :

```
`(//form[@id='a'])/div[2]/input[@id='q']`
```

But when I am running the script, it is giving error that said "no such element". Can someone please tell what I am missing in writing the xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upload your `HTML` code to let us know of the issue better. Meanwhile, Try this `.//form[@id='tsf']//input[@name='q']`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey this xpath worked for me. But I want to know what is wrong in my xpath. I am also identifying this Web Element using its parent-child xpath concept.

Comment: Well for starters, I checked `MSIE`, `Chrome` and `Firefox` and could not see `//form[@id='a']`. The value was `'tsf'` everywhere. Also `/` means immediate child whereas `//` means all nested child (childs and grandchild and great grandchild and so on). The `input` that you were trying to find was wayyy inside the `div`. Hope it explains your doubt.

Comment: Thanks hiren for your help. And yes, it cleared my doubt over the xpath I was using.

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help.